# how to make my react code more efficient

Tags: reactjs

I created a react sample app,but i feel that this does not go much well in coding standards,i am new to react,please point me the places where i can make the code efficient.I want to know the coding standards that can be used as well.
Sample methods in my project are displayed below

```
componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8095/books')
        .then(res=>{
            const books=res.data;
            this.setState({books});
        });

    axios.get('http://localhost:8095/authors')
        .then(res=>{
            const authors=res.data;
            this.setState({authors});
        })
}

onAdd(Name,ISBN,Author,Price,Year,Publisher){
    const books=this.getBooks();
    books.push({
        Name,
        ISBN,
        Author,
        Price,
        Year,
        Publisher
    });
    this.setState({books});

    axios.post(`http://localhost:8095/books`, {
        Name:Name,
        ISBN:ISBN,
        Author:Author,
        Price:Price,
        Year:Year,
        Publisher:Publisher
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    })
}

onDelete(Name){
    const books=this.getBooks();
    const filteredproducts=books.filter(book=>{
        return book.Name !==Name;
    });

    this.setState({books:filteredproducts})
    console.log(filteredproducts);

    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8095/books/${Name}`).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    })
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question better suits in [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)..

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code slightly.
You can use component did mount for initial data calls that will improve performance.
[Performing multiple concurrent requests](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
componentDidMount(){
  //Performing multiple concurrent requests and avoid multipletimes setState
  axios.all([axios.get('http://localhost:8095/books'), axios.get('http://localhost:8095/authors')])
  .then(axios.spread(function (books, authors) {
    this.setState({
      books,
      authors
    });
  }));
}

onAdd(Name,ISBN,Author,Price,Year,Publisher){
  // you can pass this args as object and directly push object in books
  const books=this.getBooks();
  books.push({
      Name,
      ISBN,
      Author,
      Price,
      Year,
      Publisher
  });
  // you should use setState callback
  this.setState({books}, () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8095/books`, {
        Name:Name,
        ISBN:ISBN,
        Author:Author,
        Price:Price,
        Year:Year,
        Publisher:Publisher
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    })
  });

}

onDelete(Name){
  const books=this.getBooks();
  const filteredproducts = books.filter(book => book.Name !== Name); // you can use single line functions in this case

  this.setState({books:filteredproducts})
  console.log(filteredproducts);

  axios.delete(`http://localhost:8095/books/${Name}`).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
  })
}
```